# What are possible causes for high external delay in loading times of web pages?

Tags: routing

Here's the scenario: 
I have a web server that serves static content through nginx. Accessing a page form this web server using the internal IP address gives a loading time of 0.2 seconds. Accessing it through the domain name, routed over the internet, it gives a loading time of 7.9 seconds.

I figured the delay could not be so long, so I visited the page through a VPN at some other location. The loading time now became 0.6 seconds.

It appears as if there is some weird routing going on when I attempt to visit a domain that refers to my own IP address. Do any of you have a possible explanation for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a local server via the external, public IP the NAT router needs to hairpin the outbound connection back into the local network. Some routers don't support that, others block it by default and most are rather slow with the double NAT it causes (source NAT for client, destination NAT for server).

The best solution is avoid this scenario by using DNS names and supplying a local record on your DNS server rather than resolving it externally (*split-brain DNS*).

Very commonly the servers are not attached to the client's LAN but to a dedicated network, possibly a DMZ. In that scenario there's no hairpinning (since the router's ingress and egress interfaces differ) but the traffic still needs to cross the router. NAT should be avoided here, often resulting in better performance.

Comment: I currently do not have a local DNS server in place yet, but this is a really good tip. Thanks!

Comment: As a temporary replacement for local DNS you can try editing the *etc/hosts* file.

Answer (score 0):

The delay or latency in access web pages from web server has many reasons to cause this issue few significant reasons are ..

1. Latency in network path . Firstly check for bandwidth utilisation on ISP . If your found high bandwidth utilisation causing latency immediately increase bandwidth of ISP
2. Check for network devices resources utilisation for devices connected in network path to reach web server from internet .. CPU , RAM , disk space utilisation in routers, Switches , firewalls  high resource utilisation causes  Low processing of frame or packet .
3. . Check for physical connectivity issue at network level  which reflects packet drops on networks .
4. if everything is seems to be fine from network end . Further check issue at destination server end . At application coding level and server resources utilisation or server request and responce time ..